# C# Text Parser Like GraphQL

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm trying to split out the following format in C# and am getting suck in a loop.

```
{
  books{
    isbn
    name
    author{
      id
      name
      birthdate
    }
  }
}
```

I essentially want to be able to identify things like Books and Author being key objects with isbn, name, id etc being properties of that object, also knowing that in this case, the author is linked to the book with the possibility that things like publisher may also follow as a sub object of books.

Any clues as to how this can be done. I keep ending up looping through it all and failing to group them correctly.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your attemps.

Comment: Are they guaranteed in that order or is it all random? You could take a look at something like ANTLR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to handle parsing. You can use a lexer, you can use a parser combinator.

In this case, I would write a simple recursive descent parser.
You basically have to keep track of opening and closing braces, and create a object tree as you go.

Parse your string by calling `GraphObject.Read(inputString)`.
You can try this code at [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zjtkRQ).

```
// A object can have to kinds of properties, simple values or sub-objects
public enum GraphElementType {
    @Object,    
    Value
}

// To make it easy to keep all values and objects in order, we define a single base class for both
// We define all elements to have a name, and set a static name for the root element
public abstract class GraphElement
{
    public static readonly string ROOT_NAME = "<ROOT>";

    public GraphElementType ElementType { get; }
    public string Name {get;}

    protected GraphElement(GraphElementType type, string name) {
        ElementType = type;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class GraphValue : GraphElement
{
    public GraphValue(string name) : base(GraphElementType.Value, name) { }
}

public class GraphObject : GraphElement {   
    public List<GraphElement> Properties {get;} = new List<GraphElement>();

    public GraphObject(string name) : base(GraphElementType.Object, name) { }


    public static GraphObject Read(string graphString)
    {
        return Read(new StringReader(graphString));
    }

    public static GraphObject Read(TextReader reader)
    {
        var root = Read(GraphElement.ROOT_NAME, reader);        
        if(ConsumeWhitespaceAndPeek(reader) != -1) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected content after root object");
        }       
        return root;
    }

    // Read an object with the given name from the given reader.
    // The reader must be positioned at the opening brace of the object.
    protected static GraphObject Read(string name, TextReader reader)
    {
        // Consume opening '{'
        if (reader.Read() != '{') throw new ApplicationException("Invalid object start");

        var o = new GraphObject(name);      
        while(true)
        {
            var next = ConsumeWhitespaceAndPeek(reader);
            if (next == -1) throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected end of input, unclosed object");

            if (next == '}')  {
                reader.Read(); // consume closing '}'
                return o;
            }

            var str = ConsumeUntilWhitespaceOrBrace(reader);
            next = ConsumeWhitespaceAndPeek(reader);         

            if (str.Length > 0 && next  == '{')
            {
                o.Properties.Add(Read(str, reader));
            }
            else if (str.Length > 0)
            {
                o.Properties.Add(new GraphValue(str));
            }
        }
    }
    // Helper method: Collect all non-whitespace, non-brace characters into a string
    private static string ConsumeUntilWhitespaceOrBrace(TextReader reader) {
        var b = new StringBuilder();

        var next = reader.Peek();
        while (next != -1 && !Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)next) && next != '}' && next != '{') {
            b.Append((char)next);
            reader.Read();
            next = reader.Peek();
        }

        return b.ToString();
    }

    // Helper method: Advance reader past any whitespace
    private static int ConsumeWhitespaceAndPeek(TextReader reader) {
        var next = reader.Peek();
        while(next != -1 && Char.IsWhiteSpace((char)next)) {
            reader.Read();
            next = reader.Peek();
        }

        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thats beyond perfect. Thanks! Never actually made use of a text reader before and it seems so obvious now. The shame.

Comment: Text reader is nicer than keeping track of a string index, because if you want to read from a file (or network stream) you can pass in a stream reader. You don't have to read the whole thing into memory.

Comment: By the way - you said in your question 'Like GraphQL'. If this is actually GraphQL, you're probably better off using a complete parser like https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/parser

Comment: I did come across that but it wasnt quite right for what I needed and came with alot of baggage. For the first stage i just needed to identify the objects and properties. Now I have them, Ill look to generate sql from that and also add filters like GraphQL